# Java Apache POI read Word (.doc) file and get named styles used

Tags: java, ms-word, apache-poi

I am trying to read a Microsoft Word 2003 Document (.doc) using poi-scratchpad-3.8 (HWPF).  I need to either read the file word by word, or character by character.  Either way is fine for what I need.  Once I have read either a character or word, I need to get the style name that is applied to the word/character.  So, the question is, how do I get the style name used for a word or character when reading the .doc file?

**EDIT**

I am adding the code that I used to attempt this.  If anyone wants to attempt this, good luck.

```
private void processDoc(String path) throws Exception {
    System.out.println(path);
    POIFSFileSystem fis = new POIFSFileSystem(new FileInputStream(path));
    HWPFDocument wdDoc = new HWPFDocument(fis);

    // list all style names and indexes in stylesheet
    for (int j = 0; j < wdDoc.getStyleSheet().numStyles(); j++) {
        if (wdDoc.getStyleSheet().getStyleDescription(j) != null) {
            System.out.println(j + ": " + wdDoc.getStyleSheet().getStyleDescription(j).getName());
        } else {
            // getStyleDescription returned null
            System.out.println(j + ": " + null);
        }
    }

    // set range for entire document
    Range range = wdDoc.getRange();

    // loop through all paragraphs in range
    for (int i = 0; i < range.numParagraphs(); i++) {
        Paragraph p = range.getParagraph(i);

        // check if style index is greater than total number of styles
        if (wdDoc.getStyleSheet().numStyles() > p.getStyleIndex()) {
            System.out.println(wdDoc.getStyleSheet().numStyles() + " -> " + p.getStyleIndex());
            StyleDescription style = wdDoc.getStyleSheet().getStyleDescription(p.getStyleIndex());
            String styleName = style.getName();
            // write style name and associated text
            System.out.println(styleName + " -> " + p.text());
        } else {
            System.out.println("\n" + wdDoc.getStyleSheet().numStyles() + " ----> " + p.getStyleIndex());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi, your edited code works with my document. But I would like to detect highlighted text. Do you have any idea of how to do that ? I googled a lot but couldn't find any clue. Thanks in advance !

Comment: @Seynorth just starting to explore this stuff so this may be no help... but there is a method of CharacterRun called "getHighlightedColor"... tried it?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest that you take a look at the sourcecode to [WordExtractor from Apache Tika](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/tika/trunk/tika-parsers/src/main/java/org/apache/tika/parser/microsoft/WordExtractor.java), as it's a great example of getting text and styling from a Word document using Apache POI

Based on what you did and didn't say in your question, I suspect you're looking for something a little like this:

```
    Range r = document.getRange();
    for(int i=0; i<r.numParagraphs(); i++) {
       Paragraph p = r.getParagraph(i);
       String text = p.getText();
       if( ! text.contains("What I'm Looking For")) {
          // Try the next paragraph
          continue;
       }

       if (document.getStyleSheet().numStyles()>p.getStyleIndex()) {
          StyleDescription style =
               document.getStyleSheet().getStyleDescription(p.getStyleIndex());
          String styleName = style.getName();
          System.out.println(styleName + " -> " + text);
       }
       else {
          // Text has an unknown or invalid style
       }
    }
```

For anything more advanced, take a look at the WordExtractor sourcecode and see what else you can do with this sort of thing!

Comment: Thanks for the response.  While I was waiting for a response, I had found an example similar to this.  This code only gives a style per paragraph, not per word or per character.  There also seems to be an issue (maybe a bug?).  If I create a new Word Doc using Word 2007 and saving as Word 97-2003, put "test" as the only text in the document, and change the style to Strong, the code tells me the style is Normal.  If I change the style to Quote, it returns Quote, but if I change it back to Strong, it returns Quote.  This happens for several styles and I am not sure why.

Comment: I haven't looked at the WordExtractor sourcecode yet, but I am fixing to.

Comment: You could try looking into the CharacterRuns of the Paragraph, and get the style from that, see if that works better for you?

Comment: `CharacterRun` doesn't seem to offer a method for retrieving the style name.

Comment: It won't - you'll want to get the style index just like a Paragraph, and look it up from that

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, Gagravarr.  I couldn't find any way to associate `CharacterRun` to a style index since there is no `getStyleIndex` method for `CharacterRun`.  Also, it seems that something is severely wrong with `getStyleIndex` or some underlying method of `Paragraph`.  It only seems to correctly return a few of the style's indexes.  This is the second time I have tried to find a use for HWPF, and this is the second time I have been unable to get any successful results.  I think I am just going to abandon using Java for reading Word Docs (Aspose.Words is too expensive for my uses).

Comment: Have you made sure you're using the latest version of Apache POI? There have been quite a few bug fixes to the word support of late

Comment: Yes.  I just downloaded it last week or the week before (can't remember).  poi-3.8-20120326.jar, poi-scratchpad-3.8-20120326.jar