# Java Apache POI read Word (.doc) file and get named CHARACTER styles used

Tags: java, ms-word, apache-poi, libreoffice

this follows on from here:

[Java Apache POI read Word (.doc) file and get named styles used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12753233/java-apache-poi-read-word-doc-file-and-get-named-styles-used)

at the time (10/2012) there was a solution to finding paragraph styles but not character styles.

And yet... if you use LibreOffice Writer to open a Word doc, for example, it does translate styles and highlighting from .doc to .odt ... so someone somewhere appears to have cracked this...

I don't know whether the Apache POI team and the LibreOffice/OpenOffice teams are in any way related, but I'd have thought the Apache POI team would've been able to get this functionality from the LO source code. Am I being naive?

Comment: The code in the answer to other question you reference ought to work fine if you look up based on a CharacterRun rather than a Paragraph - what happens if you try it?

Comment: thanks... but http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hwpf/usermodel/CharacterRun.html - CharacterRun has no "getStyleIndex" method as with Paragraph. I'm trying to find a name of or index of or reference to the *character style*.

Comment: Does [CharacterRun.getStyleIndex()](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hwpf/usermodel/CharacterRun.html#getStyleIndex%28%29) not do exactly what you need? ;-)

Comment: @Gagravarr I'm sure you are trying to help, but please read what I said and then check the API.  CharacterRun **DOES NOT HAVE** a method "getStyleIndex".

Comment: Please check the API, including the link I gave to the [JavaDocs](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hwpf/usermodel/CharacterRun.html#getStyleIndex%28%29), as you may be in for a surprise... :)

Comment: This is bizarre.  Here is the link I get from you: http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hwpf/usermodel/CharacterRun.html#getStyleIndex%28%29 - but "getStyleIndex" does not appear on that page.  Please can you spell out a URL where you believe the string "getStyleIndex" can be found... thanks

Comment: It really is there in that URL, try refreshing your page if need be

Comment: Hah! Got there in the end... I have no idea why an old version of the page was coming up... most odd.  I reloaded it and voilà!  Thanks for your persistence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Promoting some comments to an answer:

If you look at the answer given in [Java Apache POI read Word (.doc) file and get named styles used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12753233/java-apache-poi-read-word-doc-file-and-get-named-styles-used), you'll see about how Apache Tika extracts paragraph style names. Taken from the [Paragraph javadoc](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hwpf/usermodel/Paragraph.html#getStyleIndex%28%29):

> *public short getStyleIndex()*
>
> Returns the index of the style which applies to this Paragraph. Details of the style can be looked up from the StyleSheet, via StyleSheet.getStyleDescription(int)

In your case, what you're after is the equivalent but for a Character Run. That is also (now) possible, as given in the [CharacterRun.getStyleIndex() javadocs](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hwpf/usermodel/CharacterRun.html#getStyleIndex%28%29)

> *public short getStyleIndex()*
>
> Returns the index of the base style which applies to this Run. Details of the style can be looked up from the StyleSheet, via StyleSheet.getStyleDescription(int).
>
> Note that runs typically override some of the style properties from the base, so normally style information should be fetched directly from the CharacterRun itself.

To see this in action, a good example is given in the [TestRangeProperties unit test](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/scratchpad/testcases/org/apache/poi/hwpf/usermodel/TestRangeProperties.java). From there, we see code like this:

```
Range r = u.getRange();
StyleSheet ss = r._doc.getStyleSheet();

Paragraph p1 = r.getParagraph(0);
CharacterRun c1a = p1.getCharacterRun(0);

assertEquals("Normal", ss.getStyleDescription(c1a.getStyleIndex()).getName());
```

That shows you how to get the name of the base style applied to a Character Run

One final thing - for you'll need to use either a nightly build, or wait a bit for 3.11 beta 1, as some of the code mentioned isn't in 3.10 final.

Answer (score -1):

use

```
paragraph.getCTP().getPPr().getRPr().isSetB()
```

Comment: Adding a little more detail would help your answer be positively received.

Comment: This only tells you if a run is bold or not, it won't tell you the style name