# org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException

Tags: java, swing, apache, exception

I have created a search tool in java that reads doc and docx files. First, the user have to select a folder that contain the word documents. The program works fine however when I select desktop as the folder it gives the following error: org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException: Package should contain a content type part [M1.13]

Here is my code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.filechooser.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.extractor.XWPFWordExtractor;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument;
import org.apache.poi.hwpf.HWPFDocument;
import org.apache.poi.hwpf.extractor.WordExtractor;

/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/*
 * Main.java
 *
 * Created on Jul 4, 2014, 8:19:21 AM
 */
/**
 *
 * @author Yağız
 */
public class search extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    Boolean check = true;
    File[] filelist;
    /** Creates new form Main */
    public search() {
        initComponents();
        setIcon();
    }

    /** This method is called from within the constructor to
     * initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is
     * always regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
    private void initComponents() {
        bindingGroup = new org.jdesktop.beansbinding.BindingGroup();

        jFrame1 = new javax.swing.JFrame();
        jMenuBar1 = new javax.swing.JMenuBar();
        jMenu1 = new javax.swing.JMenu();
        jMenu2 = new javax.swing.JMenu();
        label1 = new java.awt.Label();
        jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();                
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jFrame1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jFrame1.getContentPane());
        jFrame1.getContentPane().setLayout(jFrame1Layout);
        jFrame1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jFrame1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 400, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        jFrame1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jFrame1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 300, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        jMenu1.setText("File");
        jMenuBar1.add(jMenu1);

        jMenu2.setText("Edit");
        jMenuBar1.add(jMenu2);

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        org.jdesktop.beansbinding.Binding binding = org.jdesktop.beansbinding.Bindings.createAutoBinding(org.jdesktop.beansbinding.AutoBinding.UpdateStrategy.READ_WRITE, jFrame1, org.jdesktop.beansbinding.ELProperty.create("CV Search"), this, org.jdesktop.beansbinding.BeanProperty.create("title"));
        bindingGroup.addBinding(binding);

        label1.setText("Keyword:");

        jButton1.setText("Find");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton2.setText("Select Folder");
        jButton2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton2ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(29, 29, 29)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jButton2)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 56, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(jButton1))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(label1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 140, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                .addGap(29, 29, 29))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(22, 22, 22)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                    .addComponent(label1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jButton2)
                    .addComponent(jButton1))
                .addGap(37, 37, 37))
        );

        bindingGroup.bind();

        java.awt.Dimension screenSize = java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        setBounds((screenSize.width-278)/2, (screenSize.height-158)/2, 278, 158);
        jFrame1.getRootPane().setDefaultButton(jButton1);
    }// </editor-fold>

    private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        //Select Folder Button
        try{
            JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
            fc.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
            fc.showOpenDialog(null);
            if(fc.getSelectedFile()==null){
                check = false;
            } 
            else 
            {
                File folder = new File(fc.getSelectedFile().getPath());
                filelist = folder.listFiles();
                if( filelist.length == 0 ){
                // dialog: folder is empty
                    check = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    check = true;
                }
             }
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error");
        }
    }                                        

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        //Find button for finding the word in word documents in the selected folder   
        String keyword = jTextField1.getText();
        int count=0;

        while (! check ) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Select a Folder!");
            return;
        }

        if(keyword.equals("")){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No keyword found!");
            return;
        }

        ArrayList result = new ArrayList();

        try
        {
            for( int i=0; i < filelist.length; i++){
                // maybe also .doc?
                if( filelist[i].getName().endsWith( ".docx" ) ){
                    count++;

                    XWPFDocument input = new XWPFDocument(new FileInputStream(filelist[i]));
                    XWPFWordExtractor extract = new XWPFWordExtractor(input);
                    Scanner scan = new Scanner(extract.getText());

                    while(scan.hasNext())
                    {
                        String word = scan.next();
                        if( keyword.equalsIgnoreCase(word) ) {
                            result.add(filelist[i].getName().replace(".docx",""));
                        break;
                        }
                    }
                }

                else if(filelist[i].getName().endsWith( ".doc" )){

                    HWPFDocument inputdoc = new HWPFDocument(new FileInputStream(filelist[i]));
                    WordExtractor extract = new WordExtractor(inputdoc);
                    Scanner scan = new Scanner(extract.getText());

                    while(scan.hasNext())
                    {
                        String word = scan.next();
                        if( keyword.equalsIgnoreCase(word) ) {
                            result.add(filelist[i].getName().replace(".doc",""));
                        break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                    continue;
            }

            if( count == 0 ){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Selected folder must contain word documents");
                return;
            }

            //...
            if(result.isEmpty()){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"No match found!");
                return;
            }
            else {
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                for( int j = 0; j < result.size(); j++){
                    sb.append( result.get(j) ).append( "\n" );
                }
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, sb.toString(), "Results", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE );
            }              
        } catch (Exception e){
           e.printStackTrace();
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error!");
        }
    }

    private void jTextField1KeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {

        if( evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER ){
            jButton1.doClick();
        }

    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(search.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(search.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(search.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(search.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                new search().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
    // Variables declaration - do not modify
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
    private javax.swing.JFrame jFrame1;
    private javax.swing.JMenu jMenu1;
    private javax.swing.JMenu jMenu2;
    private javax.swing.JMenuBar jMenuBar1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
    private java.awt.Label label1;
    private org.jdesktop.beansbinding.BindingGroup bindingGroup;
    // End of variables declaration

    private void setIcon(){
        setIconImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(getClass().getResource("icon.png")));
    }
}
```

What does this error mean and when does it occur? Can anyone help with my situation? Thanks

Comment: Have you considered [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21992071/org-apache-poi-poixmlexception-org-apache-poi-openxml4j-exceptions-invalidforma), essentially, you need to use the factory method rather then creating an instance of XWPFDocument

Comment: @MadProgrammer Have looked at the example however, I am dealing with word documents and XWPF do not have workbook methods like XSSF which is used for dealing with excel files

Comment: Yep, but the idea is you need to find the Word equivalent to load Word documents rather then using XWPFDocument directly

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12753233/java-apache-poi-read-word-doc-file-and-get-named-styles-used) and [this](http://sanjaal.com/java/tag/sample-examples-to-read-word-document-in-java/)